# Type hinting dictionaries which contain types

Tags: python, typing

I am attempting to type hint a dictionary in python. I have never had an issue prior as my key value pairs were always reasonably straight forward. However I now desire to type hint a dictionary to contain a key value pair of [str: type(MyBaseClass)] where the key is some string and the value is the type of my base class.

The issue is my linting tool and python interpreter (I'm guessing) which is python 3.11.6 are recognizing this dictionary as a dict[str, Any] rather than dict[str, type(MyBaseClass)]. I understand that this will not affect the execution of my program but it limits me when I try to access class methods of MyBaseClass after getting the value from the dictionary.

I will display some code highlighting my issue and why it is blocking me from achieving a goal.

Any help is appreciated, Cheers!

```
class MyBaseClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    @classmethod
    def some_method(self):
        # do something
        pass


class MyChildClassA(MyBaseClass)
    def __init__(self):
        pass


class MyChildClassB(MyBaseClass)
    def __init__(self):
        pass


DICTIONARY_IN_QUESTION: dict[str,type(MyBaseClass)] = {
    "some_string_A" : MyChildClassA,
    "some_string_B" : MyChildClassB,
}

def attempt_to_build_from_dict():
    class_type_A = DICTIONARY_IN_QUESTION["some_string_A"]

    class_type_A.some_method() # try to call classmethod here but interperater does not recognise it as it
                               # it sees class_type_A as an Any

if __name__ == "__main__":
    attempt_to_build_from_dict()
```

Apologies if the code is formatted strangely I attempted to manually write python code

Hovering over DICTIONARY_IN_QUESTION shows that the type is dict[str, Any] rather than the expected dict[str, type(MyBaseClass)]

I have tried using typing.Type but I understand that is just deprecated code and type works the same. I cannot use dict[str, MyBaseClass] as this is telling python that the value is an instance of MyBaseClass which I don't intend it to be.

This issue seems to originate from python interoperating the type hint of type(MyBaseClass) as if I try this type hint anywhere it displays as Any. Is there some other way of type hinting types?

Comment: Use `dict[str, Type[MyBaseClass]]`

Comment: Because `type(MyBaseClass)` is not a valid type annotation, you meant `type[MyBaseClass]`, not sure why you *called `type`*

Comment: @Barmar Cheers! very silly I forgot that i needed to use square brackets in type hints.